# Weather on the Scottish West Highland Way in March?

Tags: weather-and-climate, hiking, winter, scotland

What weather should be expected on the West Highland Way (Scotland) in March? I suppose I don't have to prepare for snow, unless I plan to hike in the surrounding mountains?

Comment: In March you can still get snow in all of the UK, but as I am not familiar with thay route I can only urge you to check it out better.

Comment: Indeed that is a very dangerous supposition you are making!

Comment: Just to explain: we do sleeping outside (bivouac) or building igloo in mountains in the winter the Czech republic (~4000 – 5000 feet), there is a lot of snow, we have proper equipment, we have even some experience even in Alps during winter. I know Scotland from all seasons except winter, which is different from Continental climate in central Europe. It's just a question which equipment is reasonable to bring (we're flying). Surely snowshoe are not needed :).

Comment: @pevik, that makes it a whole different question. An experienced mountain winter hiker should have indicated in their question that they will be prepared for some snow. As you asked the question we had to assume you wanted to do the hike in jeans and trainers.

Comment: Anecdotal hint: my snowiest walking and only skiing were in the Highlands at the very end of February so only a couple of weeks earlier.  even at the level of the passes deep snow was to be expected. Bring your winter gear (we were in boots, crampons on the steep stuff, but not snowshoes).  The same time of another year it was cool and damp

Comment: Ben Nevis is along the West Highland way and is only 1345 m high, but is considered to be a good training mountain before going to the Himalayas. Weather is simply really weird, and generally wet and cold.

Comment: @EricDuminil the [route I've seen](https://www.westhighlandway.org/the-route/) is far lower than the summit - between Kinlochleven and Fort William it only goes just above 300m.  I've actually walked (and cycled) a little bit of in Glen Nevis, but that was in summer. Scanning the map quickly the highest point might be at the top of the Devil's Staircase, just under 600m and pretty exposed

Comment: I've always considered it that 'if you're too late for the snow, you're just in time for the midges'. ;)

Comment: Yes, I remember snow on Ben Nevis in April. But I thought it's not part of West Highland Way.

Comment: I have experienced snow in Edinburgh in July, so...

Comment: @Davidmh Me too. I think I have seen snow in Edinburgh in every month except August. And in August I've seen a little fresh snow falling on the summits of Ben Macdui and Cairn Gorm.

Comment: @pevik OTOH if winter mountaineering is your thing, it would be a very nice side trip (easiest if the Glen Nevis youth hostel is open).

Comment: @Tetsujin I was very lucky last summer cycle touring.  The wind kept the midges down, only problem was it was a headwind for a week, even turning when I did. The last morning I got a taste of what the little blighters are like despite repellent and covering up - until I got moving I couldn't keep them out of my eyes and ears. The higher bits of WHW should be all right but there are long valley sections out of the wind.  I'd take a head net

Answer (score 29):

Be prepared for any kind of weather in March.

The weather in Scotland can change very quickly, and being caught on the hills with inadequate clothing can be a recipe for disaster, especially if visibility turns bad, bringing the added danger of getting lost.

> **[Scotland Weather - Expect The Unexpected!](https://www.scottish-at-heart.com/scotland-weather.html)**
>
> Due to this little country's geography, predicting the weather in Scotland can be challenging!
>
> Scottish weather can change abruptly, in fact sometimes you can feel as though you've experienced three (or even all four) seasons in just one day.
>
> One thing that you can usually depend on though... is that it's going to rain at some point.

Western Scotland is generally wetter and milder than the East, in fact [palm trees can grow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plockton) in micro-climates in the south-west.

Comment: +1, excellent advice, but one quibble - I wouldn't call Plockton the SW :-)

Comment: @Andrew agreed, it is in Western Scotland.

Comment: Those record minimums in that 'palm trees can grow' link are telling. All but one month have a record minimum below freezing. So it can freeze any time of year, even if it mostly will not be for long periods of time so near the coast.

Comment: @Willeke true, but all the "average low" temperatures are above freezing, even the winter months. In the Scottish glens (valleys) it can be cold at any time of year: they often light fires at night even in summer.

Comment: On the theme of "any kind of weather"... I did the WHW 30 years ago in the middle of summer. Of the 6 days, 1 day was hot sunshine, 2 days were showery, 2 were continuous rain, and 1 day was continuous rain and sleet with a temperature like it was February.

Comment: Take it from someone who thought they were going to die and did the WHW during September. This is solid advice, the weather can change very quickly - not only one should be prepared - you should also be sure to check weather reports daily to check for wind-storms and heavy rain.

Comment: Be prepared for anything, but *expect* plenty of rain.

Comment: There is preparing for snow and preparing for snow. It can mean something *very* different to a different individual. Should pevik be prepared to be warmly dressed and having to get some snow off their tent or should they bring crampons and ice axes?

Comment: @VladimirF, it is Schotland in March, it can be either, it can still be either in April and May.

Comment: @VladimirF the WHW is a hiking route, not mountaineering.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, that is somewhat what I am asking about. But in winter mountains many hiking routes require this sort of equipment. One slip on a short ice field can be deadly.

Comment: @VladimirF walkers usually go south to north, and the route does become more difficult. Obviously anyone contemplating the walk should study [the route](https://www.westhighlandway.org/the-route/) thoroughly. March isn't winter, but it can snow.

Comment: If you don't like the weather just wait 5 minutes (and we are fond to add: It will get worse!)

Answer (score 14):

https://www.hillwalktours.com/walking-hiking-blog/the-weather-on-the-west-highland-way/:

> Spring on the West Highland Way: The average temperature in spring depends strongly on your exact location on the route but is normally between 7 and 13 ° C. In March and April snow can still fall and the peaks are often still covered with a white blanket.

https://outdoorscott.com/best-time-year-west-highland-way/:

[image]

> **During April it can be very changeable, feeling like summer one day and winter the next**. The rainfall charts illustrate April as the second lowest rainfall month in Scotland, however in Fort William it is the 4th lowest during the year.  It should be noted that Fort William has one of the highest amounts of yearly rain in the UK, great for snow in the winter, but not so good for walking.

https://donsnotes.com/places/europe/west-highland-way.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220109003651/https://donsnotes.com/places/europe/west-highland-way.html)):

[image]

[image]

Note from https://donsnotes.com/places/europe/west-highland-way.html that the elevation changes quite a bit too:

| Dy | Section | Dist. (mi) | Ascent (ft) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [Milngavie](https://donsnotes.com/places/europe/milngavie.html) to [Drymen](http://www.undiscoveredscotland.co.uk/drymen/drymen/index.html) [image] 17x23 | 12 | 500 |
| 2 | Drymen to Balmaha [image] 20x15 | 8 | 1,200 |
| 3 | Balmaha to Rowardennan [image] 20x15 | 7 | 1,200 |
| 4 | Rowardennan to Ardlui Boat dock row-invrsn [image] 12.2x15.6 invrsn - invern [image] 12x13.5 | 12 | 1,785 |
| 5 | Ardlui to Tyndrum [image] 15.5x21 | 14 | 1,270 |
| 6 | Tyndrum to [Inveroran Hotel](http://www.inveroran.com/) [image] 14x16.5 | 9 | 1,225 |
| 7 | Inveroran Hotel to [Kingshouse Hotel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kings_House_Hotel) [image] 12x21 | 10 | 1,700 |
| 8 | Kingshouse to Kinlochleven [image] 12.2x11 | 8 | 1,388 |
| 9 | Kinlochleven to [Fort William](https://donsnotes.com/places/europe/ft-william.html) [image] 14x16.5 | 15 | 2,400 |
| Total |  | 95 | 12,668 |

[image]

Comment: Sunshine is "N/A" (on the first chart)?  Everything you need to know about Scottish weather right there.

Comment: It's worth clicking on the height profile chart (last picture).  The ascent in the table isn't all that helpful as many rolling low hills can add up to as much  climbing as one mountain, but have very different weather (stage 8 in the table peaks at nearly 600m, stage 7 at nearly 500m, several stages get to about 400m)

Answer (score 7):

[Here's the weather data for Bridge of Orchy](https://www.weather-atlas.com/en/united-kingdom/bridge-of-orchy-weather-march#snowfall).  This is the highest altitude major town on the route, but as [Franck's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/171631/3645) points out the route does go quite a bit higher.  Here's the key quote:

> In Bridge of Orchy, during March, snow falls for 11.8 days and regularly aggregates up to 281mm (11.06") of snow.

Also note that the average low at night in March is 0.2 celsius.

Comment: Bridge of Orchy is hardly a major town (it has a hotel/restaurant and a station but not a lot else); it's not even highest altitude populated place (pop. 152).  Tyndrum (a little to the south) is only marginally bigger (pop. 167) but has far more facilities - a couple of shops selling useful provisions and several places to eat.  It's also a little higher at 232m instead of 179m for Bridge of Orchy.

Comment: ... Kingshouse is considerably higher than either village but has even less - just a hotel and a few houses.  I didn't detour to it when I cycled from Fort William via Bridge of Orchy and Tyndrum to Loch Lomon in summer.  BTW [StreetView of Kingshouse](https://www.google.com/maps/@56.6510927,-4.8406255,3a,75y,242.21h,71.97t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1srPmTwmIOlutg1enlHjJHNQ!2e0!7i16384!8i8192?hl=en) has snow on the mountains in May 2021.  At a rough estimate comparing the photos to a map it extends down to about 600m, the same as the highest pass on the WHW - but 2 months later

Comment: The key point is that it’s big enough to have data at weather-atlas, which Kingshouse does not.  It’s the last place with data as you head into the worst section for snow.  Tyndrum does has data, and it’s a little less cold and less snowy than Bridge of Orchy: https://www.weather-atlas.com/en/united-kingdom/tyndrum-weather-march#climate_text_1

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder why Tyndrum is warmer and drier.  But it's a pity there are no closer datapoints  because Bridge of Orchy is a day's hike and a few hundred meters net ascent from the high point on the pass near Stob Mhic Mhartuin (Devil's Staircase)

Comment: I agree, it’s far from perfect, I wanted to find data for Kingshouse. But at least it’s really good data for one place.  I have no idea what causes the difference with Tyndrum, could be physical geography (narrower valley?) or could be something weird like where the weather instruments are relative to the town.

Answer (score 6):

From personal experience, I have encountered snow on West Highland Way in first half of March - around Crianlarich  area. There wasn't much, but it was definitely snow. Albeit that was some 15 or so years ago. I was told that wasn't common - but happened occasionally.

As others have said, be ready for anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend [Yr.no](https://www.yr.no/en) for their weather forecasts. They have good short and long range tools and are invariably accurate in that area of Scotland.

That being said, you could get anything. Rain, wind, sleet, snow, sun. Most likely the first 4.

Comment: I wonder how relevant data Yr.no has for Scotland. Or is there a better provider? Even some official measurements with graphs? (e.g. graphs for Czech Republic https://www.chmi.cz/files/portal/docs/poboc/PR/grafy/krkonose-lnk.html?l=en)

Comment: They usually have highly relevant data. They use the same base information that is provided by the UKMO, but their forecasts are more detailed and are optimised for the far north - which tend to better reflect the NW Scotland weather .